# How to ensure compile-time safety in custom data structures

Tags: go, interface

I am writing some data structures to get my feet wet and learn about the Go language and am struggling with Go's lack of generics.

In my implementations I have chosen to force each user to implement an interface so my structures could refer to these objects abstractly but I don't love my solution because this is not verified at compile-time as you will see.

#### Comparer Interface

Each object that is held in a container must implement a `Compare` function of the following signature (onerous if all you wanted to hold were raw types)

```
type Comparer interface {
    Compare(Comparer) int
}
```

You could then have various elements that implement the interface like `float64` or a custom struct:

#### float64

```
type number float64

func (n1 number) Compare(comparer Comparer) int {
    n2, _ := comparer.(number)
    if n1 > n2 {
        return 1
    } else if n1 < n2 {
        return -1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

#### Person

```
type Person struct {
    Age int
}

func (p1 Person) Compare(comparer Comparer) int {
    p2, _ := comparer.(Person)
    if p1.Age > p2.Age {
        return 1
    } else if p1.Age < p2.Age {
        return -1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

And now I can compare some of these things:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(number(2).Compare(number(4)))    // -1
    fmt.Println(Person{26}.Compare(Person{28}))  // -1
    fmt.Println(Person{26}.Compare(number(28)))  //  1
}
```

The problem here is that I should not be able to compare a `Person` and a `number`. I realize that I can check the type at runtime but I would like to find either a) a compile-time way to verify the type or b) a different method to implement data structures generically.

**Questions**

1. I know that one can do almost everything one might need with the built in data structures ... *but* how would someone make their own data structures without generics or runtime type checking?
2. Since interface implementation in Go appears to use duck typing, how does Go enforce types at compile time?

Comment: If you want to prevent the wrong type from going through your Compare function, then either check the `ok` value of the type assertion, or elide it and let the code panic. You're writing that allows the comparison of different types, then asking why it can compare different types.

Comment: Yes, I agree that I could handle things of the wrong type. I am not handling the `ok` value coming back in my implementation because it is in my test and I know that I am calling it with the write types. My main issue is that I believe it is tedious to force users to implement an interface and the interface solution can only be enforced at runtime.

Comment: You can enforce the interface implementation at compile time with something like `var _ myType = (interfaceType)(nil)` at package scope. It's fairly common practice. You're talking about passing the wrong type into a method that allows for polymorphic behavior by taking a general type and casting down to a specific one. Try the equivalent in C#, it will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. In many cases there's a generic method you can use instead that will give you the error at compile time but even in that context you run into this same thing.

Comment: The "problem" arises because the `Comparer interface {...}` has just one method and the method also takes a `Comparer` as an argument. If you redesign your solution this "problem" might vanish. In reality you do not write such code, so there is no real problem here. Compile time safety is nice but IMHO not _that_ necessary when invoking interface methods.

Comment: I would love to know why this is getting down voted. If it doesn't show research or isn't helpful, I would love to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean there's nothing unsafe about that code... There just isn't compile time safety. For example, in your method below, the first line does a type assertion on `comparer`, if it's not a number and you didn't have `_` for the second item on the LHS then it would return an error and you could act accordingly. Or you could call it without that at all and a `panic` will occur leaving it up to the caller to handle it (would be appropriate since they're the person calling the method with wrong arguments, would be like getting an `InvalidOperationException` in C#).

```
func (n1 number) Compare(comparer Comparer) int {
    n2, _ := comparer.(number)
    if n1 > n2 {
        return 1
    } else if n1 < n2 {
        return -1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

The difference between this and a language like C# is purely in generics, which allow you to do these kinds of things with more compile time safety (because you're not able to call the method incorrectly). That being said, there was a time before C# had generics and many languages before that which didn't feature them at all. These operations are no more unsafe than the casts you do routinely even in languages *that do* have generics.

Comment: I understand that a runtime check could be added to handle this situation but I disagree that performing a runtime check is as safe as a compile-time check. But my main issue is that I am attempting to write data structures and am looking for a standard/less demanding-on-users solution. I am willing to proceed with this solution if that is what is expected of programmers in Go. I am new to this environment.

Comment: @carpenter yeah, sorry I don't mean to say it is as safe, it's not. But it is all go offers. As I pointed out in a comment you can verify interface implementation at compile time but that's not what you're asking for here. You're saying "this method can take anything implementing this interface" and then wanting to enforce that the calling type and argument are the same. Like I said, generics address that issue however there are probably thousands of methods in the current version of .NET that are not generic and will behave the same as Go behaves in all cases since it doesn't feature generics

Comment: You are right. The question does not say that is what I am looking for and it does make it sound like Go cannot enforce types at all. I will fix the question.

Comment: @carpenter anyway, I generally agree with you. This is just how it is. Seems the Go team is pretty adamant about not adding generics to the language. I personally think it's Go's biggest short coming but you get used to writing a different style of code and it does work really well.